# How to Retrieve Nested array value using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{"status":1,
    "datetime":"2014-10-30 13:53:27",
    "data":{"authToken":"8019065c7362d1",
        "role":{"code":"USER","name":"User","activeFlag":1}
           }
}
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
$json='{"status":1,"datetime":"2014-10-30 13:53:27","data":{"authToken":"8019065c7362d16096eaa18df665521304a37549","role":{"code":"USER","name":"User","activeFlag":1}}}';
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach ($array as $a) {
    print_r($a);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
1 2014-10-30 13:53:27stdClass Object ( [authToken] => 8019065c7362d16096eaa18df665521304a37549 [role] => stdClass Object ( [code] => USER [name] => User [activeFlag] => 1 ) )
```

My question is third value “authToken” is not coming.
Which array property I have to use to retrieve the JASON decode value.

Comment: try $array = json_decode($json, true);

Comment: It's _JSON_, not JASON + `authToken` is not an array key, it's a property of an object (instance of `stdClass`), so you'll have to get the value using `$array->data->authToken`, or you'll have to tell `json_decode` to return an array: `json_decode($json, true);`, then get the value like so: `$a['data']['authToken']`

Comment: do you mean to access the authToken?

Answer (score 0):

Use these codes to fetch authToken from your variable `$array`.

```
$authToken = $array->data->authToken;
```

You named it as `$array`, but actually it is an object, so that you should use the method above to refer to the value nested in it.

---

Mentioned above in comments,

> try $array = json_decode($json, true); –  web developer

If use this method to decode json, you should use

```
$authToken = $array['data']['authToken'];
```

to get authToken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$json='{"status":1,"datetime":"2014-10-30 13:53:27","data":{"authToken":"8019065c7362d16096eaa18df665521304a37549","role":{"code":"USER","name":"User","activeFlag":1}}}';
    $array = json_decode($json);

    print_r($array->data->authToken);
```

Here  $array is stdClass Object and data is also a stdClass Object.

Comment: OK, your answer is correct.
But I want foreach,
Kindly answer bellow array,
This is nested array how can retrieve the data,
Can you understand my question?
`[{"status":1,
 "datetime":"2014-10-30 13:53:27",
 "data":{"authToken":"8019065c7362d1",
  "role":{"code":"USER","name":"User","activeFlag":1}
        }
},
{"status":0,
 "datetime":"2013-10-29 12:53:27",
 "data":{"authToken":"9019065c736857",
  "role":{"code":"ADMIN","name":"Admin","activeFlag":0}
        }
}
]`

Comment: please see the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = json_decode($json);
//echo '<pre>';
foreach($array as $arr){
    $token[]=$arr->data->authToken;
}
print_r($token);
```

this code will store all auth:tokens in array $token